# Log4j 2: JacksonLayout does not include contextData

Tags: java, jackson, log4j2

We have an application with a built in log viewer. Logging events are serialised as json and then sent to a socket, where it gets deserialised and displayed on screen.

For this we use a Log4j 2 SocketAppender with a JacksonLayout like this:

```
        SocketAppender appender = SocketAppender.newBuilder()
            .setName(appenderName)
            .setHost(inetAddress.getHostName())
            .setPort(port)
            .setProtocol(Protocol.TCP)
            .setLayout(JsonLayout.createDefaultLayout())
            .build();
        appender.start();
        logger.addAppender(appender);
```

Then in the log viewer code we have:

```
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                MutableLogEvent event =
                        objectMapper.readerFor(MutableLogEvent.class).readValue(inputStream);
                processLogEvent(event);
            }
```

The logging itself works, but there is an issue with the contextData. In the application, the username of the logged in user is stored in the ThreadContext and should be logged when an event happens. The pattern for the viewer looks like this: `"%d{ISO8601} %p (%X{user}) - %m%n"`, but the value for `%X{user}` is always empty. This value should come from the thread context, which is set like this:

```
ThreadContext.put("user", user.getLoginName());
```

With a debugger, I found that the user is correctly created in the contextData field of the LogEvent, but it disappears after serialising to Json.

Created LogEvent, before serialising to Json and sending it to the log viewer:

[image: Screenshot of debugger showing the contextData in the created MutableLogEvent]

After serialising:

```
{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1655893941,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 869382600
  },
  "thread" : "AWT-EventQueue-0",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "(sensitive)",
  "message" : "(sensitive)",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.log4j.Category",
  "threadId" : 25,
  "threadPriority" : 6
}
```

Note the field contextData is missing here.

The serialisation happens in the class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout.

Is there a way to include the contents of the contextMap in the Json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me not reading the documentation thoroughly.

It works by using a custom JsonLayout and setting the "properties" value to true:

```
public static JsonLayout getJsonLayout() {
    return JsonLayout.newBuilder()
        .setConfiguration(new DefaultConfiguration())
        .setProperties(true)
        .build();
}
```